# SignalR - How to PUSH data from one page to second page?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am completely new to SignalR and need to develop a web application.

**My Scenario-**

I have two aspx page. **1) ActionPage.aspx 2) DispalyPage.aspx**

Inside the **DispalyPage.aspx,** I have one div 'displayDiv'

Inside the **ActionPage.aspx**, I have one button 'btnaction'

If I click on btnaction(**ActionPage.aspx**), that time I want to PUSH data in displayDiv (**DispalyPage.aspx**).

**Question-**
Is it possible that data PUSH from one page to second page?

Any hint on this would be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of data you need to push to second page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using SignalR it self. See the following Method that I have written in the HUB

```
 public void hubMethod()
        {
           // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
           oResult = _ows.call("ana", 1, 1);
            Clients.Group("Display").addNewMessageToMainDisplay( "response is " + oResult);
        }
```

I have call this method from **ActionPage.aspx** and client side method "addNewMessageToMainDisplay" I have written in **DispalyPage.aspx** and its working now

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass data from one page to another page

1) Query String

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

2) Session

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/aspnet-session-state-example-in-c-vbnet.html

3) Cookies

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

you can use any of this...

reference link for difference
http://sanelite.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/difference-between-application-session-view-state-cookies-query-string/