# How to send data from one page to another without redirecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages – page1.aspx and page2.aspx. These two pages are used by distinct users. In page1.aspx there is a list of items.

When the page1.aspx user click on a item in the list the page2.aspx user will see a messagebox showing the item name but the page1.aspx will not be redirected to page2.aspx or any other pages. How can I do that? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Try using SignalR.

Comment: Can you give some more detail? ie. When the page2 is displayed? User clicked item on page1. Then will another user opens a browser and displays page2 ? Or page2 is already displayed, and when the user select item on page1, page2 will automatically refresh?

Comment: @Allan Please can you explain how this is a duplicate of that one. OP has asked different scenario here as compare to the other question that you have marked duplicate with.

Comment: @sumngh I was the one marking as duplicate, Allan chose a different close reason. Please explain the difference between the questions, they're asking exactly the same thing, this one just in slightly poorer wording.

Comment: @CodeCaster: This question is related to firing any event on another page by some event on first page without page redirecting, and the other question is related to refresh some section on any page without loading of whole page. And in normal words this is totally different. At least you can ask OP to refer it on another link instead of marking the question directly as duplicate.

Comment: I have to agree with OP regarding the duplicate marking of this question. The answer for both these might be similar but the one ask real-time update for one page and the other communication between 2 pages. He might be referring to real time communication between pages instead of real-time data for one page

Comment: The questions _"Realtime update of a page [based on events that may or may not happen on that same page]"_ and _"Communicate between two pages without refresh"_ are exactly the same. The number of "pages" doesn't matter. You can substitute "page" for "browser" in this question and the answer remains the same, and the duplicate still applies. If you don't agree and think this question is unique, simply click "reopen". I don't, and won't.

Comment: Exactly @Conrad, i am agree with you, answer can be same for the scenarios. But the question is totally different here.

Comment: @astin - Please look at the following link from Dan Whalin - http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-html5-web-sockets-server-with-asp-net-4-5 for some ideas

Comment: @Code the matter here is not for reopen, all the user who have rights to mark the question as duplicate can even think of the scenarios before taking this step. This will just demoralize the OP to ask anything here.

Comment: @sumngh I don't get what you're trying to say. This question is not unique, and there is plenty of explanation in the duplicate which I linked to. If it  wouldn't be a duplicate, it should be closed as too broad anyway. You are trying to find the differences between the questions, try to look for similarities instead. We don't need another five answers saying "Use SignalR".

Comment: @sumngh a question that looks more like this one is for example [SignalR - How to PUSH data from one page to second page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783330/signalr-how-to-push-data-from-one-page-to-second-page), but it is a terrible duplicate target because it is too narrow and doesn't explain why SignalR (or comparable techniques) would help.

Comment: @JustAnotherCodeLover Both pages are already displaying and the users are totally different. While page2 user click on a link item the page1 user will see a messagebox showing the selected item but the page2 will not redirect to any other page.